# Creating a setup step in LoadUI

Tags: soapui, loadui

I have a REST request to create a new user.  I also have a request to retrieve the user's ID number. I want to load test retrieving the ID number multiple times in LoadUI. The problem is that I only need to create the user once but LoadUI loops back and creates the user each time.  Is there a way to make the request to create a new user to only run once or in setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isolate the create user in a separate testcase.

Then disable that testcase

Then create a Setup Script that runs your testcase. Or maybe even just that one teststep.

Then your create user will only be called once at the start.